# Merging repositories with file history

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-rebase

I have 3 separate git repos on Bitbucket. I want to merge them all in a single repository, each of them in a separate subdirectory. I managed to do that like this (in an empty repo, after doing the initial commit):

```
    1.git remote add -f old_1 
    2.git checkout -b old_1 old_1/master
    3.mkdir old_1
    4.git mv !(old_1) old_1
    5.git commit -m "old_1 subdir" 
    6.git checkout master
    7.git merge -S --no-edit --allow-unrelated-histories old_1
    8.git commit -m "merged old_1"
```

I repeated these steps for old_2 and old_3 repos, and then

```
    9.git push
```

Everything worked fine, i can see all the commits in bitbucket, but no file history.

I have alse tried `git rebase -i --root master` after merging all the repos, but it's giving me a conflict for almost every commit (there are a lot of commits in total, ~4700).

My question is if is there any way to merge these repos without losing file history neither commit history?

Comment: Git does not have file history. The only history in a Git repository is (are?) the commits. The commits are the history; the history is commits; asking about a file tells Git: *looks through all the commits, and only tell me about commits that touch this file.* Note that if you add `--follow` to the `git log` arguments while telling Git to tell you only about one file, Git will attempt to detect renames, and will search for the *old* name of the file once it steps back to the older commit that has the old name.